# c++ template error - RBTree

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ templates and I have not managed to fix this error. 
In my main method I am creating an instance tree for the Rbt calling the templates item and key as int. The error I am being told is

> no matching for call to 'RBt :: RBt()'

and the warning message I am getting is:

> RBt ::RBt(Item, Key)[with Item = int; Key= int]

the code in my main method:

```
#include "Nod.h"
#include "RBt.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    Nod <int, int> x = Nod<int, int> (0, 3); // Nod.h

    RBt<int, int> tree;
    tree.Insert(tree, &x);

    return 0;
}
```

RBt.h:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;

    template <class Item, class Key> class RBt
    {
    private:

        Nod<Item, Key> *root;

    public:
        Nod<Item, Key> NIL;

        RBt(Item item, Key key){
            root = 0;
        }
        void Insert(RBt<Item, Key> T, Nod<Item,Key> *z);
    };

template<class Item, class Key> void RBt<Item, Key> ::Insert(RBt<Item, Key> T, Nod<Item,Key> *z)
        {
            Nod<Item, Key> *newNode = NULL;


            if(root->getValue() == z->getValue()){
                //skip doubles
            }
            else if(root->getValue() > z->getValue()){
                if(root->getLeft() == NULL){

                    newNode = z;
                    root->setLeft(newNode);
                }
                else{
                    this->Insert(T,z->getLeft());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(root->getRight() ==NULL){

                    newNode =z;
                    root->setRight(newNode);
                }
                else{
                    //this->Insert(root->getRight(),z);
                }
            }

            z->setLeft(newNode);
            z->setRight(newNode);
            z->color = "RED";
            //z-> setColor("RED");
            InsertFixUp(T,z);

        }
```

Nod.h:

```
    template <class Item, class Key> class Nod {
    public:
        Nod *left;
        Nod *right;
        Nod *parent;

        int value;
        string color;
        Key key;
        Item item;

        Nod(Item item, Key key){
            this->key = key;
            this->item = item;

        }

void setLeft(Nod<Item, Key> *left){
        this-> left = left;

    }

    Nod<Item, Key> *getLeft(){return this->left;}

    void setRight(Nod<Item, Key> *right){
        this-> right = right;

    }
    Nod<Item, Key> *getRight(){return this->right;}
        void setValue(int value){
        this->value = value;
    }

    int getValue(){ return this->value;}

    void setColor(string color){
        this->color = color;
    }

    string getColor(){return this->color;}
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your definition for Node (or is it Nod...you have both)?

Comment: I have edited the question with the Nod class.

Comment: do you need the insert method?

Comment: Only if you want it to compile...

Comment: Side note: I assumed in my answer that you're doing this for some sort of assignment. If this is for any project in which you get freedom to choose, use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead - it's bug-free, faster, and more idiomatic. It's also typically implemented as a red-black tree.

Comment: yes it is for an assignment, and I tried using std::map, but could not understand it and only have a week to complete it. But when I have time I will try it with this. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, it's much, much, faster to figure out `std::map` than to unnecessarily reinvent the wheel; there's no bugs to work out that way. What was giving you trouble with that?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one constructor, and it takes arguments of types `Item` and `Key`, which, based on this line: `RBt<int, int> tree;`, you specified to both be `int`. Pass two ints to the constructor like so: `RBt<int, int> tree(0,0);`. Alternatively, add the following to RBt.h:

```
RBt() = default;
```

to add back the default constructor (which is no longer automatically generated if you declare any other constructor).

Also, in C++11, you can set `root = nullptr;` directly in the class definition - you don't need to do so in the constructor. Prefer `nullptr` to setting pointers to 0. It's clearer and also gets rid of the possibility of an obscure compiler ambiguity.

Comment: thanks for the reply, 
The second option you gave me did not give any errors in the main but i got this error  - no matching function for call to ‘Nod<int, int>::Nod()’. 

And the same error if I try the first option.

Comment: Sure, you attempt to use the default `Nod` constructor for the line `Nod<Item, Key> NIL;`, so because there is no default constructor available you end up with the same problem. Add `Nod() = default;` in the Nod.h file, or `Node() { /* more fancy stuff here */ }` if you want other behavior.

Comment: You could also similarly call the one constructor you wrote with `Node(0,0)` (or other values) as before. The point is that you're invoking a constructor that doesn't exist. To invoke a non-default constructor, if you mean for NIL to be non-static (as it is now), do so in the constructor or just assign it in the class definition, if you intended it to be static instead, add the line `RBt::NIL(0,0);` in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You need constructor like that

```
RBt(){
    root =0;
}
```

Comment: when i do that I get these errors: 
no matching function for call to ‘Nod<int, int>::Nod()’ and when i do the Nod constructor the same as above I get an error in the main saying no matching function for call to ‘Nod<int, int>::Nod(int, int)’.